# UNetbootin installation of Ubuntu Server fails and restarts computer

Tags: linux, installation, usb-flash-drive, boot, unetbootin

I tried to install Ubuntu Server from a flash drive using UNetbootin, because my optical disc drive is broken. When I created the bootable drive using UNetbootin, there was no problem.

When I tried to install it on my computer, after booting it shows the UNetbootin menu where you can install Ubuntu Server. But when I choose to install it, my computer restarts and I land at the UNetbootin menu again. This process repeats.

Is there something wrong with my computer? Is the drive broken or is that a software error?

How can I install Ubuntu Server from the flash drive, then?

Comment: Have you tried another USB drive? How about trying the USB drive on another computer?  Have you tried a different Ubuntu image/version? Aside from the optical drive being broken, was the computer previously working OK?

Comment: i already tried another usb drive, but the problem still accoured.
but in other computer it working.

before i try to install ubuntu server, my computer working perfectly.